# camera roll image is bigger than the camera preview

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapture

I am creating a camera app. I can take a image and the image is passing back to a view controller to show the image. It also saved to the camera roll.
If I compare the image with the camera preview to the saved image, it seems like that the camera preview is a little bit zoomed in.

Image from camera preview:
[image]

Image from Gallery:
[image]

This is my code so far from the camera preview:

```
let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
    captureSession.startRunning()
```

How can I make the camera preview to the same size as the saved image?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the `videoGravity` setting. `.resizeAspectFill` will resize the preview to fill the whole view, even when that means cropping content.

If you want to see the whole frame, set it to `.resizeAspect`. This will introduce black bars, though.

Comment: and how can I get the actual size of the camera preview?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the captured Image to have the same size as the camera preview. You should set    `videoGravity = .resize`